# Error when trying to update via linked server (mssql -> mysql) - Select works

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, odbc

I am having an issue when trying to do an update via a linked server.  Error is the following:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "**LINKED_SERVER_NAME" returned message "Data provider or other service returned an E_FAIL status.".
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKED_SERVER_NAME".
```

I have no problem selecting data but any time I try to do an update it fails. My update code:

```
Update [LINKED_SERVER_NAME]...[Table_Name]
SET post_content = 'alert'
where ID = 5061
```

This is my select statement which DOES work:

```
select top 100 * from [LINKED_SERVER_NAME]...[Table_Name] where ID = 5061
```

I am using:

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008
- Trying to connect from MS SQL -> MySQL via ODBC Connector 5.2 (5.1
  has same issue)

UPDATE
I have tried to use "OPENQUERY" -> this does not work either

Comment: From memory the syntax you are looking for is: `UPDATE OPENQUERY(LINKED_SERVER_NAME, 'SELECT post_content FROM Table_Name WHERE ID = 4061') 
SET post_content = 'alert'` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx

Comment: Is openquery a new thing.  I was successfully able to do this about 2 years ago.  I just tried recently which is where I ran into problems.

Comment: I've always had to do it when the linked server was a non-SQL Server instance. Otherwise if the Linked Server is another SQL Server instance, standard ANSI SQL seems (mostly) okay. One other thing to check, I guess, is if the account details the Linked Server have been set up with have UPDATE permissions on the underlying TABLE_NAME.

Answer (score 1):

[OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) is not new but it is far more reliable when dealing with non-microsoft linked servers.

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY (LINKED_SERVER_NAME, 'SELECT post_content FROM Table_Name WHERE ID = 5061') 
SET post_content = 'alert';
```

- Do not use [ ] square brackets in mysql queries; you can use apostrophe instead.
- Check that you have update permissions on the table.
- Try running the update directly on a mysql connection. This may be an error not related to linked servers.
- Is the mysql table a view? It may not be configured correctly as an updatable view. 
  [MySQL CREATE VIEW Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html)

If this still doesn't solve it, paste your actual openquery code into the question.